# Firebase not working anymore on iOS flutter

Tags: ios, xcode, firebase, flutter, cocoapods

Im building a small project with firebase it used to work on both iOS and android emulator but since couple of days ago its not working anymore on iOS and after pod install it shows this error:

Running pod install...
CocoaPods' output:
↳
      Preparing

```
Analyzing dependencies

Inspecting targets to integrate
  Using `ARCHS` setting to build architectures of target `Pods-Runner`: (``)

Finding Podfile changes
  - Flutter
  - cloud_firestore
  - firebase_auth
  - firebase_core

Fetching external sources
-> Fetching podspec for `Flutter` from `.symlinks/flutter/ios`
-> Fetching podspec for `cloud_firestore` from `.symlinks/plugins/cloud_firestore/ios`
-> Fetching podspec for `firebase_auth` from `.symlinks/plugins/firebase_auth/ios`
-> Fetching podspec for `firebase_core` from `.symlinks/plugins/firebase_core/ios`

Resolving dependencies of `Podfile`

Setting up CocoaPods master repo
  $ /usr/bin/git remote set-url origin https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git
  [!] Failed: /usr/bin/git remote set-url origin https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git
  $ /usr/bin/git checkout master
  [!] Failed: /usr/bin/git checkout master
[!] Unable to add a source with url `https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git` named `master-1`.
(The `master` repo is not a git repo.)
You can try adding it manually in `/Users/myname/.cocoapods/repos` or via `pod repo add`.

/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/cocoapods-1.7.5/lib/cocoapods/sources_manager.rb:40:in `rescue in find_or_create_source_with_url'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/cocoapods-1.7.5/lib/cocoapods/sources_manager.rb:43:in `find_or_create_source_with_url'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/cocoapods-1.7.5/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:173:in `block in sources'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/cocoapods-1.7.5/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:172:in `map'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/cocoapods-1.7.5/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:172:in `sources'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/cocoapods-1.7.5/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:938:in `block in resolve_dependencies'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/cocoapods-1.7.5/lib/cocoapods/user_interface.rb:64:in `section'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/cocoapods-1.7.5/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:937:in `resolve_dependencies'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/cocoapods-1.7.5/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:118:in `analyze'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/cocoapods-1.7.5/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:398:in `analyze'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/cocoapods-1.7.5/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:221:in `block in resolve_dependencies'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/cocoapods-1.7.5/lib/cocoapods/user_interface.rb:64:in `section'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/cocoapods-1.7.5/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:220:in `resolve_dependencies'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/cocoapods-1.7.5/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:156:in `install!'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/cocoapods-1.7.5/lib/cocoapods/command/install.rb:51:in `run'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/claide-1.0.3/lib/claide/command.rb:334:in `run'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/cocoapods-1.7.5/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:52:in `run'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/cocoapods-1.7.5/bin/pod:55:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/local/bin/pod:22:in `load'
/usr/local/bin/pod:22:in `<main>'
```

Error output from CocoaPods:
↳
      fatal: not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git
      fatal: not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git

Error running pod install
Error launching application on iPhone Xʀ.

Comment: Might be a corrupt cocoapods cache. Try `rm -rf ~/.cocoapods` and retry

Comment: @PaulBeusterien didn't work :(